# ¿Cómo colocar un cuadro con código de ejemplo y formateado en una pagina web usando Angular7?

Tags: javascript, html5, angular7

La idea es Colocar un cuadro con código de ejemplo dentro de mi pagina web usando angular, algo como lo hacen en la documentación, he visto las etiquetas en HTML como <"code-example> o <"code-tabs> pero no sé como hacerlo funcionar.
[image: Código de ejemplo]

Answer (score 0):

no se si ayude en algo, pero existe una pagina web (codePen) que te permite insertar código funcional en una pagina web y poder ejecutarla ahí mismo

**[CodePen](https://blog.codepen.io/documentation/features/embedded-pens/)**

de igual forma si necesitas crear solamente código para insertar como ejemplo te sugiero que **generes tu mismo** un formato para tu código, al final de cuentas solo son divs y botones con iconos (de igual forma no dudo que exista un modulo node para formatear código)
[image: ejemplo de divs unidos y modificados para mostrar codigo]